# iOS universal link not work

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I'm currently testing universal link on my app. I have uploaded **apple-app-site-association**, edit my app's entitlements file, but it still not work. Click an universal link in Mail just direct me to safari browser.

I noticed that each time I click the universal link, the console on my macbook logs the following: 
**1/25/16 2:35:43.483 PM useractivityd[389]: application (null) considered for activity continuation, but rejected because it will not run using a suitable architecture**

Is anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: check the value of "Architectures" and make sure it includes `"Standard architectures(armv7, arm64)"`

Comment: @Justlike Yes, the target architectures are right.

Comment: Always use actual devices to test universal links. Simulator doesn’t support universal links.

Comment: @MrWaqasAhmed I'm using my iPhone to test, it's linked to my macbook so I can debug.

Comment: what's your phone model? iphone 5c? Maybe you need to add **armv7s**

Comment: @Justlike Yeah, I added it.

Comment: Take a look at complete integration of universal links here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609667/how-to-support-universal-links-in-ios-app-and-setup-server-for-it/35609668#35609668